# Java vararg pass lambda and values

Tags: java, lambda, variadic-functions

I'm trying to unite lambdas and simple values in varag.

```
public static void Log(String format, Object ... args) {
    final Object[] fmt = new Object[ args.length ];
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            fmt[i] = args[i] instanceof Supplier  ?
                     ( (Supplier) args[i] ).get() :
                     args[i];
    final String s = String.format( format, fmt );
    System.err.println( s );
}

final Supplier
    s = () -> "aaa",
    d = () -> 111;
Log( "%s %d %s %d", "bbb", 222, s, d );    // OK, OUTPUT: bbb 222 aaa 111
Log( "%s %d %s %d", "bbb", 222, () -> "aaa", () -> 111 );  // COMPILE FAIL
```

ERROR: method Log cannot be applied to given types; REQUIERED String,Object[] found: String,String,int,()->"aaa",()->111 REASON: varargs mismatch; Object is not a functional interface

Is it possible to pass both lambdas and values to vararg?

Comment: varargs must have the same type, so try this: `Log( "%s %d %s %d",(Object) "bbb", (Object) 222,(Object)  () -> "aaa",(Object)  () -> 111 );`

Comment: @ Timothy Truckle That solution will still give a compiler error.

Comment: I've tried (Object), but it does not help. (Supplier) casting solved the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the error message

> Object is not a functional interface

You can only create a lambda for a functional interfaces (one with exactly one abstract method)  Object is not an interface and it doesn't have any abstract methods so you can't create a lambda of this type.  What you can do is

```
Log( "%s %d %s %d", "bbb", 222, (Supplier) () -> "aaa", (Supplier) () -> 111 );
```

This way the compiler knows what sort of lambda you intended to implement.

By comparison you could write the following and this would behave differently in your method.

```
Log( "%s %d %s %d", "bbb", 222, (Callable) () -> "aaa", (Callable) () -> 111 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Object` is not a `@FunctionalInterface`. That being said you can pass a simple anonymous instance like this:

```
Log( "%s %d %s %d", "bbb", 222, new Supplier<String>() {
            @Override
            public String get() {
                return "aaa";
            }
        });
```

This method can be used if you don't want to use unchecked casts which will result in a compiler warning.

If you still want to cast your lambda it can be done this way:

```
Log( "%s %d %s %d", "bbb", 222, (Supplier<String>) () -> "aaa");
```

Comment: My answer is an alternative to yours.

Comment: What is the problem with that? Lambdas are syntactic sugar for anonymous inner classes annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`.

Answer (score 0):

For the compiler there is no way to tell what type of functional interface is used when you delcare them (unlike the first one, since you defined that in the variableType)

So a fix would be casting the supplier. E.g. (not tested)

```
Log( "%s %d %s %d", "bbb", 222, ((Supplier<String>)() -> "aaa"), ((Suplier<Integer>)() -> 111) );
```

Hope this points in the right direction.